# reading file problem with python username and passowrd recovery system

Tags: python, python-3.x, recovery

This Is a recovery system where the user enters their unique code to recover their details. when the unique code is entered it takes their details from a text file and then it prints their username and password. Then they are given a choice to change their password. The problem that I have is that when I type the old password in it sayes that the password is not in that specific line. The format in the file is this:

`(unique code) username: (username) password: (password)`

```
global password1, password2,
check = True
while check:
    hash1=input("\n"+"Enter your unique code to recover your username or password ")
    with open("mount.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            text = line.strip().split()
            if hash1 in text:
                print(line)
                check = False
                change = input("Do you want to change your password? [y,n]")
                while change not in('y', 'n'):
                    change = input("Do you want to change your password? [y,n]")
                if change == "y":
                    check = True
                    with open("mount.txt","r+") as file:
                        for line in file:
                            text = line.strip().split()
                            while check:
                                password1 = input("Enter old password ")
                                password2 = input("Enter new password ")
                                if len(password2) < 5:
                                    print("New password is too short")
                                elif password1 not in text:
                                    print("Old password is incorrect")
                                elif password1 in text:       
                                    s = open("mount.txt").read()
                                    s = s.replace(password1, password2)
                                    f = open("mount.txt", 'w')
                                    f.write(s)
                                    f.close()
                                    print("Password has been successfully changed")
                                    check = False

            elif len(hash1) < 32 and (check == True):
                print("Unique code not found please try again")
                break
```

So when I enter the unique code it shows the right line then when I try changing the password it keeps on saying the password is not in that specific line.

Comment: No need to declare those two variables global at the start. They're outside of a function. Using this keyword in Python outside of a function has no meaning and does nothing.

Comment: @Torxed oh ok i'll remove it from my code

Comment: Also, doing `if password1 in text` means that if the password is `Abcdefghijlk`, all i have to do is enter `b` and that will equal `True`. That's bad, I guess.

Comment: @Torxed Thats a bit odd because I made the password in the file `Abcdefghijlk` and the typed in `b` it still sayes the old password is incorrect

Comment: @Torxed Also do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I suggest you debug your expectations, do a `print(password1, 'vs', text)` to find why it's saying they're not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, when looping through lines in the text file, if `hash1` is not in ANY line, it will tell you that the code is not found, and immediately break.

To fix this, you should break or return from inside your `if hash1 in text` conditional, then test `if len(hash1) < 32 and (check == True)` which will now only run AFTER checking all the lines in the file.

Also, supposing text is 'aslhngbadf username: bob password: alice', `line.strip().split()` will be `['aslhngbadf', 'username:', 'bob', 'password:', 'alice']`, so checking that `password1` is in `text` won't work for one letter of the password.  It will, however, work if you enter the word 'password:' or 'bob'... , check that things match explicitly like `if password1 == text[4]`.

Finally, when you reopen and itterate over the file, you move from the line where your text matched, back to the top of the file.  Don't open mount.txt twice.  `text` still remains available and unchanged from the first time you set it.

Comment: thanks for this fix but do you know how to fix the other problem with changing the password?

Comment: See my edit.  Added last paragraph.  You're unnecessarily iterating over the file twice, meaning that you match hash1 on a certain line, but then start checking passwords not on that line, but from the top of the file.

Comment: Its now working since I got rid of the extra code but now you can change anything in that specific line not just the password

Comment: Again, check that `password1 == text[4]` instead of just being `in text`.  Then you can only change that exact thing.  I'll say, you're likely to run into a number of issues.  If two people have the same password, you'll change them for both, if one user has the same username and password, they'll both change, and you have some efficiency and security issues.